# How to sort an array according to shorted distance Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I want to sort an array such that each element is in the shortest distance from previous location.

array is such like that

```
locations=[{"loc1",lat,long},{"loc2",lat,long},{"loc3",lat,long},{"loc4",lat,long},{"loc5",lat,long}]
```

the function to calculate the distance is this:

```
var distance = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
{
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
  var theta = lon1-lon2;
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  dist = dist * 1.609344 ;

  return dist;
}
```

This function when passed the value provide the distance between two location.

The starting point is the first element of locations array
now i want a function that will take array and return the sorted array.

Comment: Sounds like a Travelling salesman problem https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Your array isn't a valid array array of objects. This isn't a valid object: `{"loc1",lat,long}`

Comment: Yes it is but i am unable to solve this in JavaScript.@ManuAntony

@Adam lat and long will be the values of the locations its just example
it will be like:
    {"loc1","13.426785","44.475847"}

Comment: The JS object should look like `{ "name": "Loc1", "lat": 1231231, "lon": 234235232 }`

Comment: @NeerajSharma - paste `{"loc1","13.426785","44.475847"}` into your console and you'll see an error - it's not a valid JS object.

Comment: ok i understand @Adam  although i do have valid json in my array.

Comment: Why are you using trigonometric functions to calculate distance? Surely you can do it with basic squares and square root operations? Or does that come out more performance intensive somehow? `distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(latitudeDifference, 2) + Math.pow(longitudeDifference, 2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom function to the sort method on the Array prototype, like this:

```js
locations = [
  ["loc1", 1, 1],
  ["loc2", 3, 3],
  ["loc3", 2, 2],
  ["loc4", 5, 4],
  ["loc5", 3, 5]
];

var distance = function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
  var theta = lon1 - lon2;
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  dist = Math.acos(dist);
  dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  dist = dist * 1.609344;

  return dist;
};

locations.sort(function(a, b) {
  var origLat = 0,
    origLong = 0;

  return distance(origLat, origLong, a[1], a[2]) - distance(origLat, origLong, b[1], b[2]);
});

console.log(locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without real locations couln't test but something like below should do the job :

*(I dont know Google Map API, maybe you can find a better way to do this...)*

```js
var locations = [{
  name : "loc1",
  lat : 1001,
  long : 2001
 }, {
  name : "loc2",
  lat : 150,
  long : 630
 }, {
  name : "loc3",
  lat : 151,
  long : 631
 }, {
  name : "loc4",
  lat : 850,
  long : 56
 }, {
  name : "loc5",
  lat : 960,
  long : 698
 }
];

var distance = function (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
 var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
 var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
 var theta = lon1 - lon2;
 var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
 var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
 dist = Math.acos(dist);
 dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
 dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
 dist = dist * 1.609344;

 return dist;
}

var locationWithDistFromPrevious = locations.map(function (l, i) {
  if (i === 0) {
   l.dist = 0;
  } else {
   l.dist = distance(l.lat, l.long, locations[i - 1].lat, locations[i - 1].long)
  }
  return l;
 }).sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.dist - b.dist
 });

var locationWithDistFromFirst = locations.map(function (l, i) {
  if (i === 0) {
   l.dist = 0;
  } else {          
   l.dist = distance(l.lat, l.long, locations[0].lat, locations[0].long)
  }
  return l;
 }).sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.dist - b.dist
 });


document.getElementById("resultFromPrev").textContent = JSON.stringify(locationWithDistFromPrevious, null, 4);
document.getElementById("resultFromFirst").textContent = JSON.stringify(locationWithDistFromFirst, null, 4);
```

```html
<body>
  Sort by previous item<br/>
  <pre id="resultFromPrev"></pre><br/>
  Sort by first item dist <br/>
  <pre id="resultFromFirst"></pre><br/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the distance calculation inside a sort function:

Because the distance calculation is a pretty intensive, caching distances in an object will make it much faster so you're not calculating the same distance more than once in your sort method:

```
var startingLoc = {lat:0.000,lng:0.000};//your starting location;
var distanceCache = {}; //a cache to hold your distance calculations

//sort the locations - assumes loc1 is {lat:some number, lng: some number}
locations.sort(function(loc1,loc2) {
    var loc1Key = loc1.lat+'-'+loc1.lng;
    var loc2Key = loc2.lat+'-'+loc2.lng;

    if(!distanceCache.hasOwnProperty(loc1Key)) {
      distanceCache[loc1Key] = distance(startingLoc.lat,startingLoc.lng,loc1.lat,loc1.lng);
    }

    if(!distanceCache.hasOwnProperty(loc2Key)) {
      distanceCache[loc2Key] = distance(startingLoc.lat,startingLoc.lng,loc2.lat,loc2.lng);
    }

    return distanceCache[loc1Key] - distanceCache[loc2Key];

 });

distanceCache = null; //done with distanceCache
```

Comment: thanks but is there any way such that i pass an array to the sort function and it return me the sorted array as i am still finding my way through JavaScript.

Comment: `locations.sort` sorts the array **in place** such that after you call `locations.sort....`, the objects in the `locations` array are in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably headed down a pretty big rabbit hole on this one. I'd look here first to see if you can use the Maps API [Google Map V3, how to get list of best driving route for multiple destinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804073/google-map-v3-how-to-get-list-of-best-driving-route-for-multiple-destinations). The `optimizeWaypoints` setting is meant to return a list of locations in optimal driving order.

Obviously this isn't the same as a pure distance comparison, but it may be suitable for your needs.

Comment: i tried this but the map do not work well in south korea so cant use it.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate

Comment: actually it for an app i need an array of sorted value so that i will later plot it on map according to the array.